# How do I calculate the similarity of a word or couple of words compared to a document using a doc2vec model?

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

In gensim I have a trained doc2vec model, if I have a document and either a single word or two-three words, what would be the best way to calculate the similarity of the words to the document?

Do I just do the standard cosine similarity between them as if they were 2 documents? Or is there a better approach for comparing small strings to documents?

On first thought I could get the cosine similarity from each word in the 1-3 word string and every word in the document taking the averages, but I dont know how effective this would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a number of possible approaches, and what's best will likely depend on the kind/quality of your training data and ultimate goals.

With any `Doc2Vec` model, you can infer a vector for a new text that contains known words – even a single-word text – via the `infer_vector()` method. However, like `Doc2Vec` in general, this tends to work better with documents of at least dozens, and preferably hundreds, of words. (Tiny 1-3 word documents seem especially likely to get somewhat peculiar/extreme inferred-vectors, especially if the model/training-data was underpowered to begin with.)

Beware that unknown words are ignored by `infer_vector()`, so if you feed it a 3-word documents for which two words are unknown, it's really just inferring based on the one known word. And if you feed it only unknown words, it will return a random, mild initialization vector that's undergone no inference tuning. (All inference/training always starts with such a random vector, and if there are no known words, you just get that back.)

Still, this may be worth trying, and you can directly compare via cosine-similarity the inferred vectors from tiny and giant documents alike.

Many `Doc2Vec` modes train both doc-vectors and compatible word-vectors. The default PV-DM mode (`dm=1`) does this, or PV-DBOW (`dm=0`) if you add the optional interleaved word-vector training (`dbow_words=1`). (If you use `dm=0, dbow_words=0`, you'll get fast training, and often quite-good doc-vectors, but the word-vectors won't have been trained at all - so you wouldn't want to look up such a model's word-vectors directly for any purposes.)

With such a `Doc2Vec` model that includes valid word-vectors, you could also analyze your short 1-3 word docs via their individual words' vectors. You might check each word individually against a full document's vector, or use the average of the short document's words against a full document's vector.

Again, which is best will likely depend on other particulars of your need. For example, if the short doc is a query, and you're listing multiple results, it may be the case that query result variety – via showing some hits that are really close to single words in the query, even when not close to the full query – is as valuable to users as documents close to the full query.

Another measure worth looking at is "Word Mover's Distance", which works just with the word-vectors for a text's words, as if they were "piles of meaning" for longer texts. It's a bit like the word-against-every-word approach you entertained – but working to match words with their nearest analogues in a comparison text. It can be quite expensive to calculate (especially on longer texts) – but can sometimes give impressive results in correlating alternate texts that use varied words to similar effect.

Comment: I trained my model on the Wikipedia corpus and initially, I was trying to compare the vectors of the small and large document directly which may be why the results were not as good as I was hoping for based on your explanation.

I did have my setting set to dbow_words=1 so I will look into WMD and comparing the individual word vectors to the documents vectors but when comparing the individual word vectors to the overall documents vector would you recommend I split it the document into paragraphs and analyse against each paragraph vector or would this not have a noticeable effect?

Comment: You also mention that unknown words have random vectors how does the word vectors counteract this? e.g. doc2vecmodel['pineapple'] where pineapple is an unknown word?

Comment: If comparing tiny-doc & large-doc vectors isn't working well, it could be for a lot of reasons – maybe it's the fact tiny-docs may not get good vectors (how are you creating the tiny-doc vectors?), but could be other things as well – it's hard to guess without seeing more of your setup. (For example, are large-doc to large-doc comparisons working better?) Whether splitting docs into smaller chunks could help would depend on your real goals & experimentation – do you need paragraph rather than full-document results? Are "best paragraph" matches more useful to your users than full-doc matches?

Comment: Unknown words – that didn't appear in the training corpus at all – don't have random word-vectors, they have no word-vectors at all. If you try `doc2vecmodel.wv.['pineapple']` and 'pineapple' wasn't in the training data, you'll get an error. On the other hand, if 'apple' was in the training data, then for some modes `doc2vecmodel.wv.['apple']` will return a usefully-trained word-vector, but a plain PV-DBOW (`dm=0, dbow_words=0`) model will just return a weak random untrained word-vector that really shouldn't be used for anything.

Comment: I am creating the tiny-doc vectors using model.infer_vector(tinydoc). For large document comparisons aka if I do a google search term and compare the top 2 documents to one another I see high accuracies such as 0.7+ and if I compare the same doc to itself I'll see an accuracy of 0.99. The problem comes when comparing a tiny doc (1-3) words to one of these documents the similarity for a single word is very low aka 0.06 other unrelated words will have a negative similarity which makes sense. But 0.06 suggests they aren't related which I don't think is correct.

Comment: I actually fixed this, I made a mistake and was not preprocessing my tiny document which has improved my accuracy by quite a bit. I still intend to look into averaging the word vectors to see if that has a useful effect on the accuracy. Thank you for all your help btw you answer every gensim question and it is amazing.

Comment: Ah, yes, it is a common error to pass just a string, or something not quite preprocessed/tokenized the same as training data was, to `infer_vector()`. Also when debugging inference: (1) in recent versions it will by default use the model's `epochs` value. That might be as low as 5 if haven't specified it, while 10-20 is far more common in `Doc2Vec` published work, and smaller docs/corpuses may benefit from even more. (Especially, tiny docs being inferred may benefit from many more epochs, to simulate a larger doc.) (2) Checking that re-inferring a training doc yields a similar vector is…

Comment: …a good sanity check. Because of inherent randomness/jitter used by the algorithm, the re-inferred vector won't be identical. But the original doc-vector, as trained in model training, should almost always the nearest to the re-inferred vector, and if not, then either inference should be further improved (preprocessing, choice of `epochs`), or the original model training had problems - maybe too little data, too large of a model prone to overfitting, too few `epochs`, etc.